# Sharing a Visual Studio 2019 repository on your local network

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository

We'd like to have a shared VS 2019 repository on our local network. With the new VS 2019 GIT experience, it's easy to share using Github, but we're not allowed to put our code outside of the LAN.  So far I've only see command line GIT solutions.  Has Anyone done this?  How?  We've tried the VS-2019 GIT properties but it doesn't seem to push changes to a shared drive.  We have servers we could dedicate as shared hosts if necessary.

Comment: What error are you getting? I know you cannot show us the real path to the repository, but can you tell us an approximation of the URL you are cloning from?

Comment: And did you clone from a bare repository?

Comment: I tried setting the repository in the VS properties for GIT, it gave no errors, but didn't change anything.  I started with a local repository.